# How to merge many small files into fewer larger files

Tags: python

I am trying to merge many (100+) small (log)files into fewer larger files using Python. The restriction on the output files is the maximum filesize, which in this example should not exceed 100 KB (in my use case this limit is about 4 GB, because later on I need to load these files into memory for analysis).

Random toy data for a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) can be created by executing:

```
import numpy as np

toy_files = 100  # number of files 
chars = np.array(list(chr(ord("a") + i) for i in range(26)))
digits = np.array(range(1, 7))
length = 60  # characters per line 

for _ in range(toy_files): 
    fname = "".join(np.random.choice(chars, 16))
    x = np.random.choice(digits, 1)[0]
    y = np.random.choice(digits, 1)[0]
    z = x + y
    n = z ** 4
    content = "".join(np.random.choice(chars, n))
    lines = [content[i:i+length] for i in range(0, len(content), length)]
    
    with open(f"{fname}.txt", "wt") as outfile:
        for line in lines: 
            outfile.write(f"{line}\n")
```

My attempt to merge the toy data into files of max. 100 KB each:

```
import os

cwd = os.getcwd()
input_dir = "./"

stack = []

for root, directories, filenames in os.walk(input_dir):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith(".txt"):
            root = root.replace(cwd, ".")
            input_file = os.path.join(root, filename)
            stack.append(input_file)

stack.sort()

f_size = 0  # initialize for first output file 
max_f_size = 10**5  # = 100,000 bytes = 100 KB
counter = 0 

while len(stack) > 0: 
    input_filesize = os.path.getsize(stack[0])
    while f_size + input_filesize < max_f_size: 
        with open(f"part_{counter}.txt", "a") as outfile:
            with open(stack[0], "rt") as infile:
                for line in infile:
                    outfile.write(line)
        os.remove(stack[0])  # remove file 
        stack.pop(0)  # remove reference to file from stack
        f_size = os.path.getsize(f"part_{counter}.txt")
    counter += 1
    f_size = 0  # initialize for next output file
```

**My problems**

1. When `len(stack)` reaches 0 while `f_size + input_filesize < max_f_size`, this causes `IndexError: list index out of range` (because the stack is empty and no element from stack can be opened `as infile`). I don't understand why this happens, since `while len(stack) > 0` should prevent this.
2. The resulting files sometimes exceed `max_f_size`, which is no serious problem for my use case, but again: I don't understand why this happens, since `while f_size + input_filesize < max_f_size` should prevent this.

I welcome any answer that provides me with an insight and helps me resolve these problems. A combination of whole files would be preferable, but that's not a hard criterium. Otherwise a cut should only be made at a line ending. The original order of the lines must be preserved.

**Update**

I have added [the latest revision of the script](https://pastebin.com/kzAMDEUL) to Pastebin after implementing the accepted answer and suggestions for improvement of performance.

Comment: What do you want to happen when `max_f_size` is exceeded?

Comment: `max_f_size` should never be exceeded. before `max_f_size` is exceeded: no more input file is added to the current ouput file, `counter` is raised by one and a new output file is created.

Comment: Do you want to combine whole files into larger ones, or are you happy for the first half of a file to be added to one file, while the other half (or more parts) are added to other files? Does it matter that such a cut could be made anywhere, or is that only allowed at a line ending?

Comment: Instinctively, I would say that a combination of whole files would be preferable. Not a hard criterium. Otherwise a cut should only be made at a line ending. The original order of the lines *must* be preserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to update `input_filesize` with the new input file (solves problem 2). While you're at it, break out of the loop when there isn't one anymore (solves problem 1). So add this to the end of your inner `while` loop:

```
        if stack:
            input_filesize = os.path.getsize(stack[0])
        else:
            break
```

Comment: Very concise and effective. Would not have thought of using `if stack`.

Comment: @marianoju Since you mentioned speed in another comment: You could also do `outfile.writelines(infile)` or use [`shutil.copyfileobj`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj) instead of your inner `for`-loop. And using binary mode instead of text mode to avoid decoding/encoding. And it might be better to open the outfile *once*, *outside* of the inner `while`-loop, instead of repeatedly opening it for appending. I just didn't do anything like that since you asked to adapt only as far as necessary.

Comment: And you were absolutely right to do so, since performance was not in the scope of my original question. I have implented your suggestions and tested with 1,000 toy files: 0.1541 vs. 0.1997 seconds is a significant improvement in performance. Thanks!

Comment: @marianoju That's actually a disappointingly small speedup. I think it's because your toy files are tiny. With your real data, which sounds like it has much larger input files, I'd expect using binary mode and shutil to make it maybe three times faster based on some testing.

Comment: My real data consist of gzipped text files, so it's difficult to compare. But creating larger toy data files is trivial. With `toy_files = 10**3`, `n = z**5` and `max_f_size = 10**7` (resulting in ca. 400 MB of data) the execution of the merger itself (after sorting the stack) takes 1.5167 seconds (improved) vs. 1.6927 seconds (original). It _is_ faster, but not three times faster.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that your `while` loops are outside of your appending:

The for-loop here:

```
                for line in infile:
                    outfile.write(line)
```

Will run to completion *before* the `while` loop conditions are checked again:

```
while len(stack) > 0: 
    input_filesize = os.path.getsize(stack[0])
    while f_size + input_filesize < max_f_size: 
        ...
                for line in infile:
                    outfile.write(line)
```

Which makes sense as to why you would be exceeding your max: you are not checking the  byte-count added for each new line you are appending.

**Edit**: Someone pointed out below (in an unfriendly way) that I read too quickly and that I was mistaken in the reasoning here. Anyway, I'll leave the suggestion below in case it's useful.

As an aside, your problem is similar to a problem that appears in some database implementations where the goal is to build a set of reasonably-sized, well-organized files to search over later on. You may find some background on this topic relevant to your problem.

Anyway, to simplify what you have, you might instead iterate over your `stack` variable, which removes some bookkeeping around it. I would also change the ordering of file-access, because we may wish to switch to a **new write-file** when our size maximum has been reached, which may happen *in the middle of iterating*. For this reason, I'd probably manually open and close files while iterating. Here's my suggestion:

```
counter = 1
current_file = open(f"part_{counter}.txt", "a")
current_file_size = 0

for fname in stack:
    print(f"OPENING new READ file {fname}")
    with open(fname, "rt") as infile:
        for line in infile:
            new_length = len(line)  # using string len here for convenience
            if current_file_size + new_length > max_f_size:
                current_file.close()
                counter += 1
                current_file = open(f"part_{counter}.txt", "a")
                print(f"OPENING new WRITE file {current_file}. Old file size: {current_file_size}")
                current_file_size = 0

            current_file.write(line)
            current_file_size += new_length
    print(f"DELETING READ file {fname}")
    os.remove(fname)  # remove file

current_file.close()  # almost forgot to close the last-open file...
```

Results in file-sizes like this:

```
❯ ll
total 872
drwxr-xr-x  7 user  staff    224 Dec 19 11:42 ./
drwxr-xr-x  5 user  staff    160 Dec 19 11:30 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  99944 Dec 19 11:42 part_1.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  99969 Dec 19 11:42 part_2.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  99949 Dec 19 11:42 part_3.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  99941 Dec 19 11:42 part_4.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  36297 Dec 19 11:42 part_5.txt
```

Comment: First part is nonsense, as they're checking in advance whether `f_size + input_filesize` will be below `max_f_size`. I've already explained the real reason for exceeding in my answer.

Comment: I'd say better create the output files with `"w"`.

Comment: Using string length gives too low numbers if their real files have characters that are encoded with multiple bytes.

Comment: That's why I wrote "for convenience." It's the kind of thing they can work around once they have a working poc.

Comment: I saw that, but "convenience" doesn't indicate that it might be wrong.

Comment: @erewok Thanks for taking to time to rewrite the script! I understand why you chose to iterate over the `stack` variable in a for loop and this approach works just fine. However, while the result meets my expectations, your answer does not actually answer my question(s). BTW estimating the `current_file_size` for every line of input creates an massive overhead that affects overall performance (execution time: 0.0174 seconds vs. 0.0552 seconds when compared with my revised script).

Comment: That makes sense. That line in my example was just a readability hack. You can also capture the characters (or bytes, if you open with `b`) by capturing the result of the `write` method call and just check after the write if you've exceeded your max. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects for more info